# Change icons position using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios6, icons, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController. Can I change the order of the position in which the icons appear?

Because I can't find a way to do it, they are always appearing in the same order (Mail, Facebook, Twitter, ...) and I have to change the order.

Thank you.